# Control to use for Reusable container for content/content template?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I am creating a container whose style will be used across the application. It essentially is a 'pop up' but won't spawn in a new window. The general structure of my app is one NavigationWindow and many pages. So I get started with the following Template, defined in my Resource Dictionary:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RainbowModalTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">        
    <Canvas Height="540" Canvas.Left="492" Canvas.Top="296" Width="945">        
        <Border x:Name="Modal" Height="540" Width="945"  Background="#ec2016" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15" Style="{DynamicResource RainbowModalBox}">
            <Border.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" Rect="0,0,945,540"/>                   
            </Border.Clip>
                <Image Source="Resources/RainbowModal/rainbow.png" Height="247" Width="947" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="-2" Canvas.Top="293" ClipToBounds="True" />         
        </Border>               
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So when I want to 'consume' this, I want to be able to implement this control but provide my own content inside, (buttons, text, etc). However because I am new to WPF I am unsure what control or controls to use, and what structure to lay this out as. Below is sample 'consumer' of the object. Someone will click a button in the application and that will set this objects' visibility to be Visible :

```
<Control x:Name="RequestMoreInfoModal" Template="{DynamicResource RainbowModalTemplate}" Canvas.Left="494" Canvas.Top="250" Visibility="Collapsed"></Control>
```

I  know this probably isn't the most kosher way to do this, so I am open to suggestion. My specific concerns:

I know "Control" isn't the right type. But I don't know what is appropriate and it appears Canvas and other controls do not allow Templating. What control should I use?

how do I implement this Template and also allow the consumer to define their own content within the Template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I eneded up doing is using a ControlTemplate and ContentPresenter.

Here is the definition of the reusable content in my ResourceDictionary:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RainbowModal" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Canvas>
        <Border x:Name="Modal" Height="540" Width="945"  Background="#ec2016" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="2" Style="{DynamicResource RainbowModalBox}">
            <Border.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry  
                        RadiusX="{Binding CornerRadius.TopLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}"
                        RadiusY="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                        Rect="0,0,945,540"/>
            </Border.Clip>
            <Canvas>                    
                <Image Source="Resources/RainbowModal/rainbow.png" Height="247" Width="947" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="-2" Canvas.Top="293" ClipToBounds="True" />
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And here is the 'consumption' of that content.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="RequestMoreInfoModal" Canvas.Left="489" Canvas.Top="122" Template="{StaticResource RainbowModal}" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock FontSize="78" Foreground="White" Width="903" Canvas.Top="28" Canvas.Left="20" Height="298" Text="Scan your card to receive an email with more information." TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Serif72 Beta" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Width="250" Height="76" Content="CLOSE" Margin="350,350" Style="{DynamicResource PurpleInfoButton}" FontSize="28" Click="Button_Click_1" ></Button>
     </Canvas>
</ContentControl>
```